# Cannot open source file "d3dx9.h" With DirectX installed

Tags: c++, c, directx

**EDIT: It was a cache issue I had to restart Visual Studio code**

It says its not included but I use this code `#include <d3dx9.h>;` and here are my
[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcr35.png) (Include Directores: `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`) (Library Directories: `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`)

I see a lot of people ask this question but no one of the answers seem to work. If it matters I am using visual studio code 2019. Also I checked the the Include folder of where I installed DirectX and it has the d3dx9.h.

Comment: Please read [ask]. [Edit] your post to include an [mcve]. Please do not post images of text. Where is `DXSDK_DIR` defined?

Comment: Another option to using the legacy DirectX SDK for the deprecated D3DX9 library is to use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cache issue with VSC 2019